# How do I set the max height on a Flutter Horizontal Bar Chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using the horizontal bar chart for flutter that autosizes the bar heights.

https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/horizontal_bar_label.html

[image]

When I have a single bar as in this example I want to fix a maxheight (e.g. 10px) for the bar.  How is this configured?

I'm looking at the constructor here but I haven't found a solution
https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/BarChart-class.html

```
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300.0,
        height: 250.0,
        child: charts.BarChart(
          [
            charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
                id: 'Sales',
                domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
                measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
                data: localData,
                colorFn: (_, __) =>
                    charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
                labelAccessorFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) =>
                    'Category 1: ${sales.sales.toString()}')
          ],
          animate: true,
          vertical: false,
          barRendererDecorator: new charts.BarLabelDecorator<String>(labelPosition: charts.BarLabelPosition.inside
          ),
          domainAxis:
          new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: are you asking for the bar width? If it is, update your question

Answer (score 5):

There is no possibility to do this for the moment according to this [issue](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/167).

But I think you can bypass this by creating others items with transparent color or change the Chart library code.

#### EDIT `2021/03/23`

There is still no solution from the google team but [Boken's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645964/10286880) seems to be a good one.

Answer (score 5):

## Workaround

You can try to wrap `BarChart` in to `SizedBox`, wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView`.

## In pseudocode

```
- SingleChildScrollView
       - SizedBox
              - charts.BarChart
```

## Flutter

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 2000,
    child: HorizontalBarLabelChart(
      getData(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

## Size calculation

Height of the `SizedBox` can be calculated base on number of data, e.g.:

```
numerOfElements * 50
```

## Before

For 100 elements

[image]

## After

For 100 elements (so height is `5000` because `100 * 50`)

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer

Answer (score 4):

Try to do this -

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 50.0), // adjust the height here
  child: Your_chart_here, // place your chart here
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  However, this limits the entire chart, but not the bars contained therein.  It works ok for a chart with a single bar, but our charts vary between 1-5 bars so if it's limited for a single bar setting the chart with 5 does not work.